# NULL assigning to associative array

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, associative-array

I wanted to assign NULL to an associative array. How can I do it?

```
TYPE t_test IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
l_arr t_test;
l_arr:=NULL-- Which is giving error.
```

Comment: An associative array can't be null; do you mean you want to empty it, or assign a particular position as null?

Comment: I want to empty it. Or if I want to assign a particular position as null, in that can also how can I do it then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to empty it.

Use the [`delete` collection method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-E43509F6-5044-4B17-9516-2EB4BDDD5173):

```
l_arr.delete;
```

> Or if I want to assign a particular position as null, in that can also how can I do it then?

Just assign null to that position:

```
l_arr(2) := null;
```

You can also delete a specific position:

```
l_arr.delete(1);
```

Demo of both:

```
declare
  type t_test is table of pls_integer index by pls_integer;
  l_arr t_test;

  procedure show(p_label varchar2) is
    l_idx pls_integer;
  begin
    dbms_output.new_line;
    dbms_output.put_line(p_label || ': count = ' || l_arr.count);
    l_idx := l_arr.first;
    while l_idx is not null loop
      dbms_output.put_line('  ' || l_idx || ' -> ' || l_arr(l_idx));
      l_idx := l_arr.next(l_idx);
    end loop;
  end show;
begin
  l_arr(1) := 1;
  l_arr(42) := 42;

  show('a');

  l_arr(2) := null;
  show('b');

  l_arr.delete(1);
  show('c');

  l_arr.delete;
  show('d');
end;
/
```

```
a: count = 2
  1 -> 1
  42 -> 42

b: count = 3
  1 -> 1
  2 -> 
  42 -> 42

c: count = 2
  2 -> 
  42 -> 42

d: count = 0


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```